# Is the First Order prejudiced against non-humans?

Tags: star-wars, aliens, the-force-awakens, first-order

We know that the Empire was prejudiced against non-humans. In Legends, it was a lot more explicit, but even in Canon, we don't see any non-human Imperial officers and the Empire was fine with enslaving and committing genocide against non-humans, as seen with the Wookiees and Lasats, respectively.

Is the First Order also prejudiced in this way?

On one hand, they based themselves heavily on the Empire, and besides Snoke, they don't seem to employ any non-humans or have any non-human officers.

On the other hand, they are lead by Snoke, who doesn't seem to be human.

So to what degree were they prejudiced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The First Order inherited the Galactic Empire's anti-alien policy.

Quoting Wookieepedia on the [First Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/First_Order) (emphasis mine):

> Prerecorded speeches often filled the airwaves, in which General Hux would often comment on the depravity of the Republic ... and **unchecked alien advances throughout the Outer Rim**. Following which stories of First Order victories ... Within many of the labor camps and mining operations in First Order space, a large number of individuals involved were from **aliens species**.

The above is cited to be sourced from *Before the Awakening*.

- Unchecked alien advances throughout the Outer Rim: The definition of "alien" used here is debatable. It probably means alien species but it can possibly mean alien immigrants - which can be human - too.
- Large number of individuals involved (within many of the labour camps and mining operations in First Order space) were from alien species: This is undeniable proof that the Imperial anti-alien policy is alive and well. Back in the golden age of the Empire, alien species that aren't subjected to genocide - such as Wookiees and Twi'leks - are subjugated and controlled by enslaving them into forced labour.

Considering that the First Order was founded by the Empire's military loyalists who refused to be subjected to the terms of surrender agreed upon in the Galactic Concordance, they are likely to retain the core principles of the New Order, such as the concept of human superiority.

The anti-alien policy is more of a propaganda tool than something they genuinely believed in to the degree the Nazi leadership in Germany probably did.

- Snoke is not necessarily non-human. While his species isn't yet identified, there is still the chance that, as a powerful and ancient dark side user, he may just be another human who, like Palpatine, is "scarred and deformed".
- The Empire, the original anti-alien nation, made extensive use of alien Inquisitors who are very unlikely to be discriminated against like regular alien slave labourers.

If it suits their purposes, the Empire was very willing to use aliens who swore fealty to the Empire. The First Order, who adhered to everything that made the Empire great, would likely adopt this outlook as well.